# How to download newly uploaded videos from a youtube channel?

Tags: command-line, downloads, youtube, wget, youtube-dl

I want to set up a script that uses `wget` to download a video from a channel on youtube, they upload everyday so I want `wget` to download the newly uploaded video without me having to go on youtube to get the video's URL. How could I achieve this? If `wget` can't do it, is there any other command line software that can?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's already a script for that: **`youtube-dl`** can download videos from [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/) or other video platforms.

#### Installation

The program is provided via the repositories and can be installed from there, however as youtube often change things and the program gets ongoing updates **in this special case** I recommend installing the latest version from [github](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) with these commands **instead**:

```bsh
sudo apt remove youtube-dl # uninstall the repo version
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl # download
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl # make it executable
hash -r # hash
```

If you installed the program this way you're able to update it using:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

#### Usage

Here are some video selection options that could be useful for you:

```
--playlist-start NUMBER
          Playlist video to start at (default is 1)
--playlist-end NUMBER
          Playlist video to end at (default is last)
--date DATE
          Download only videos uploaded in this date
--dateafter DATE
          Download only videos uploaded on or after this date (i.e.  inclusive)
```

#### Examples

Download today's videos including resume of partially downloaded files:

```
youtube-dl --date now -- 'PLFs4vir_WsTyXrrpFstD64Qj95vpy-yo1'
```

<sup>for www.youtube.com/watch?list=**PLFs4vir_WsTyXrrpFstD64Qj95vpy-yo1**, while the full link also works</sup>

Download all videos from the last seven days using the URL list in `file`:

```
youtube-dl --dateafter now-7days -a file
```

Download all videos from the last month using the URL list in `file`, but don't touch any already downloaded videos located in the directory:

```
youtube-dl --dateafter now-1month -a file -w
```

See [`man youtube-dl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/youtube-dl.1.html) for much more.